# Why does this nested list comprehension generate an error?

Tags: python, zip, python-3.x, list-comprehension

```
conn_request, weights = zip(*[
    ((conn, request), request[2])
    for conn in unchoked_conns
    for request in conn.peer_requests
])
```

Generates:

```
    for conn in unchoked_conns
ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack
```

I cannot work out what I'm doing wrong. I think it has some thing to do with the dependence of `request` on `conn`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> a, b = zip(*[])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack
```

Your LC produces an empty list. Try verifying that `unchoked_conns` has any elements.

Comment: This has got to be a bug, or an oversight. All but the empty list case work fine.

Answer (score 0):

zipping an empty list returns a single empty list, hence the assignment fails.  That is consistent with the zip help, which clearly says:

```
The returned list is truncated in length to the length of the shortest argument sequence
```

In your case, the shortest argument sequence has length 0.